# PyGtk3: Get current Entry text color

Tags: colors, pygtk

I currently have the following in my PyGtk3 program that changes the Entry text color to red if the input is not acceptable:

```
...
self.entryIpAddress = Gtk.Entry()
self.entryIpAddress.connect('changed', self.entryIpAddress_changed)
...

def entryIpAddress_changed(self, widget):
   if not valid_ip_address(self.entryIpAddress.get_text()):
      self.entryIpAddress.override_color(Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, Gdk.RGBA(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0))
```

This works, but I want to return the text back to it's original color.  Is there a method I can use to find out what the Entry's text color is before I start changing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more searching, I found out how to do it:

```
style = self.lblIpAddress.get_style_context()
self.entryIpDefaultColor = style.get_color(Gtk.StateType.NORMAL)
```